# Android Ensure URL on LAN is active before sending url string

Tags: android

My app sends communication via http over wifi from android devices to the router and eventually reaches a device. This string is dependent entirely on the ip address of the device on the LAN.

The string looks like this:

```
http://*standardstuff*(networkIP)*finishingstuff*
```

I can send and receive communication perfectly as long as the device is on the network. However, I run into problems if the device is no longer on the network or its ip has changed while the app is running. I get the following error...

```
07-14 15:22:40.656: I/System.out(14655): I-O side Error
07-14 15:22:40.656: W/System.err(14655): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.0.29:80 timed out
07-14 15:22:40.660: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
07-14 15:22:40.664: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
07-14 15:22:40.664: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-14 15:22:40.664: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-14 15:22:40.667: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
07-14 15:22:40.667: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-14 15:22:40.671: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-14 15:22:40.675: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-14 15:22:40.675: W/System.err(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:608)
07-14 15:22:40.675: W/System.err(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-14 15:22:40.679: W/System.err(14655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-14 15:22:40.679: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-14 15:22:40.683: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-14 15:22:40.683: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-14 15:22:40.687: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-14 15:22:40.687: W/System.err(14655):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-14 15:22:40.691: W/dalvikvm(14655): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015578)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:3272)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:720)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:746)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2511)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5337)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5649)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2786)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2647)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2622)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity.resetStats(MainActivity.java:906)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:631)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-14 15:22:40.726: E/AndroidRuntime(14655):    ... 4 more
07-14 15:22:43.082: I/System.out(14655): I-O side Error
07-14 15:22:43.167: W/System.err(14655): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.0.29:80 timed out
07-14 15:22:43.167: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
07-14 15:22:43.167: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
07-14 15:22:43.167: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:608)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at com.example.airscapefancontroller.MainActivity$RequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
07-14 15:22:43.171: W/System.err(14655):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
07-14 15:22:43.175: W/dalvikvm(14655): threadid=10: thread exiting with uncaught exception     (group=0x40015578)
```

Which makes sense given the fact that the doinbackground I think its referencing is attempting to connect to a url that is no longer active. It is valid so it will pass all validity checks but it will not return anything useful.

Here is the doinbackground:

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String responseString = null;
        try {
            response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                out.close();
                responseString = out.toString();
            } else{
                //Closes the connection.
                response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                resetStats();
                stopRefreshService();
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            System.out.println("Client Side Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            resetStats();
            stopRefreshService();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I-O side Error");
            e.printStackTrace();
            resetStats();
            stopRefreshService();
            return null;
        } 
        return responseString;
    }
```

Here is the button click method that launches things

```
    public void controlClick(View v){

    if(actionIpSet()){
        //This starts the service that runs every 30 secs for 2 minutes the same code found in the do in backgroun.
        startRefreshService();
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.imageButton1: 
                  new RequestTask().execute("http://"+ actionIP + "/fanspd.cgi?dir=1");
                  break;

            case R.id.imageButton2:
                new RequestTask().execute("http://"+ actionIP +"/fanspd.cgi?dir=2");
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton3:
                new RequestTask().execute("http://"+ actionIP +"/fanspd.cgi?dir=3");
                break;

            case R.id.imageButton4:
                new RequestTask().execute("http://"+ actionIP +"/fanspd.cgi?dir=4");
                break;

            case R.id.Button02:
                Refresh();
                break;
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("ActionIP is not set: " + actionIP);
    }
```

Comment: You have not posted enough lines of your logcat. If the url is invalid you will get a very nice descripting exception.

Comment: Sorry about that. I do get that before and after and that exception is nicely caught (its in yellow and does not cause my app to crash) I can put some of that up a minute as well.

Comment: I just added the full error log. I have narrowed the problem a bit. I now suspect it is not due to the service but actually due to the doinbackground async task. I have disabled all services and received the same error without the services running.

Comment: I just answered it but don't have enough cred to post my answer. Basically I was trying to post stuff from doinbackground to UI thread. Yikes! Alright thanks for the help SO community!

Comment: You have a ConnectTimeoutException. Clearly mentioned in the log. MainActivity line 1 and 608. Which code line? 10.0.0.29 is ip address of? Please tell if you use device or emulator. Or did you solve the problem already? Then be clear about that.

Comment: Hi Greenapps. Thanks for your help. As you can see in my previous post I was actually able to solve the issue. Yes I was getting a timeout which was causing the crash (it should not do this) The reason it was crashing was because I posted a method that was attempting to affect the UI thread from the background in the case of a connection error.

Answer (score 0):

I answered my own question. As you might be able to see in the above doinbackground code there are 3 instances of the following method **resetStats();**

Found in all the following error cases:

```
 } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            //error case 1
            resetStats();
            stopRefreshService();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        System.out.println("Client Side Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error case 2
        resetStats();
        stopRefreshService();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("I-O side Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        //error case 3
        resetStats();
        stopRefreshService();
        return null;
    }
```

the method is too long and unnecessary to post in the answer. Basically why it was causing problems was because it is a method that attempts to run on the UI thread. **This is not possible and will cause your app to crash.** I completely forgot that 1. this method was running on a separate thread and 2. that attempting to run it from the background would cause such troubles.

I want to thank Greenapps for responding to my issue. I'd also like to thank the greater SO community for being here and answering questions.